# Is it possible to share Findbugs settings between Ant and Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, ant, findbugs

Is there a way to share Findbugs filters set in Netbeans with Ant, perhaps generating an xml file which can be used as the include filter option in the Ant build file? Would the reverse also possible (import filters into Netbeans)?

Comment: The FindBugs plugin seems to be configured only inside NetBeans from my five minutes of checkout for options. You might want to try the [Software Quality Environment](https://kenai.com/projects/sqe/pages/Home) which includes FingBugs, Checkstyle, PMD, and Dependency Finder. Perhaps it allows external configuration.

Comment: I checked out SQE, there's no settings available from the IDE but I rooted around the NetBeans appdata and found a config file (UserPreferences.findbugs - not xml) which contained the rules. I was hoping there was an already existing method to convert between, but I might just make my own tool to do this.

Answer (score 0):

FindBugs offers a cloud storage feature that can be used store,share and discuss warning evaluations.You can try it.